# Capybara can't find button to click by xpath or text, button does not have id or name

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

I am testing this page that I have to fill up a form and only when all fields are filled and valid, the button is enabled to click, however, when trying to find the button to click I always get the message that capybara was unable to find the button or element or however I try to find it.
The button does not have a name or an id, which makes it harder.

[screenshot of the part of the code while inspecting element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wai1y.png)

```
<button class="btn btn--highlight _159vaYHuibqRdI3OZTALCW">
<!-- react-text: 182 -->
Jetzt kaufen
<!-- /react-text -->
<!-- react-text: 183 --> — <!-- /react-text -->
<!-- react-text: 184 -->
94,01&nbsp;€
<!-- /react-text -->
<span class="spinner">
</span></button>
```

When the size of the browser changes, the button text changes, however by default size the text of the button is "Jetzt bestellen" and when larger  "Jetzt kaufen"
Ways I already tried to click this button:

**@browser**.click_button('Jetzt bestellen', wait:10)

**@browser**.within ".btn btn--highlight" do
    @browser.click_on "Jetzt bestellen"
  end

**@browser**.find_button('Jetzt bestellen', wait: 10).click

**@browser**.find(:xpath, '//button[text()="Jetzt bestellen"]', wait: 10).click

Comment: Do you have `Capybara.exact` set to true by any chance?  If not, is the button outside the current scope (i.e. are you inside a within block that doesn't contain the button).  Note:  `click_button` is implemented as `find_button(args...).click` so it's no surprise your third attempt was no different than the first. Your fourth attempt wouldn't work because the content of the button is more than just "Jetzt bestellen". Please add the exact error message you get to your question.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/twalpole/14cd6c69c91b3d54cf2bd994375a019b is a gist taking the html you show, putting it into a document and then showing capybara finding an clicking on it.  Are you sure the text is "Jetzt bestellen" when your test runs? and not the "Jetzt kaufen" you show in the html?  Could you try just doing `click_button('Jetzt')` and seeing if that passes.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got around this issue when testing an Angular app.

```
@browser.find('button', text: 'Jetzt bestellen').click
```

Without a hrefs on the links and buttons a few capybara finders don't work like they would if they had a href.

Comment: In Capybara links do require 'href' attributes, or for you to specify an `href: nil` option to click_link.  This is because the html spec says it's not a link if it doesn't have an href - just a link placeholder.  `button` elements though don't have any such requirement in Capybara (just that they're not disabled)